# Ansible win_chocolatey module - System.OutOfMemoryException error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to install software on Windows server 2008 R2 via win_chocolatey module. It doesn't work as it throws error:

> [ERROR] - Chocolatey had an error on WIN-2008r2 (with user Administrator): System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method) at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Object target) at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LoopCompiler.CreateDelegate() at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterLoopInstruction.Compile(Object frameObj) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Command "choco install" works when used on the server.

I tried to increase memory limit for PowerShell and for WinRM.

> set-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
>
> winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="2048"}'

What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I needed this fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2842230/-out-of-memory-error-on-a-computer-that-has-a-customized-maxmemorypershellmb-quota-set-and-has-wmf-3.0-installed

Now it works.